# Save resized images iteratively to subdirectories

Tags: python, image, save, iteration, resize

I have a directory called 'Photos-test', with multiple subdirectories. Each subdirectory contains two subdirectories, "Camera Photos" and "Edited Photos." "Camera Photos" contains .jpg images. I need to iteratively run through each subdirectory and resize the images within each "Camera Photos" subdirectory and then save these resized images into each "Edited Photos" subdirectory. The code I have below saves the images into each "Camera Photos" subdirectory. I need to save them into their matching "Edited Photos" subdirectories. Can someone assist?

```
import PIL
import os
from PIL import Image

path_to_images = "C:/Users......"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path_to_images, topdown = False):
   for name in files:
      if name.endswith('.JPG'):
         filename = os.path.join(root, name)
         img = Image.open(filename)
         imageResize = img.resize((3552,2664))
         imageResize.save(filename[:-4]+"_Edited.jpg", 'JPEG')
```

Comment: Do the subdirectories have the same name?

Comment: The directory tree looks like this:
Photos-test
 Folder 1
  Camera Photos
  Edited Photos
 Folder 2
  Camera Photos
  Edited Photos

….and so on.

Comment: then do it like this `imageResize.save(filename[:-3] + '/Edited Photos/' + "_Edited.jpg", 'JPEG')`